# Show Flutter Navigation stack

Tags: flutter

I want to see the navigation stack in Flutter. Is it possible to use the `Navigator` class to print the navigation stack and other meta info about what's inside the Navigator?

Printing the `Navigator` with the `print()` method just gives the `Navigator` as a string.

Expected result: `Navigator : { params...., params.... }`

Comment: if this is only for a specific use case, you could provide that and we could help you around that issue. I couldn't see any case where you would need the navigation history. If you wan't to know where you're coming from just create a parameter that you can pass to your next page that contains the page it's coming  from.

Comment: checkout this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/62591160/9689717

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think the only way you could do this currently is to override the `Navigator` class and keep track of the Routes yourself.

If you look at the [Navigator source code](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/b5c5bae42bbecb71abdecc1484b5b3986ffc3bd0/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/navigator.dart#L1309) there is a variable called `_history` which contains all the navigated routes but there's no way to access it unfortunately.

Answer (score 13):

Perhaps the `Navigator`'s `observers` parameter could help you? Though it would involve manually keeping track of the internal stack state of the `Navigator`. You could then operate on the `routeStack` member as necessary.

```
...
Navigator(
    observers: [MyNavigatorObserver()],
    onGenerateRoute: ...,
  )
...


class MyNavigatorObserver extends NavigatorObserver {
  List<Route<dynamic>> routeStack = List();

  void didPush(Route<dynamic> route, Route<dynamic> previousRoute) {
    routeStack.add(route);
  }

  void didPop(Route<dynamic> route, Route<dynamic> previousRoute) {
    routeStack.removeLast();
  }

  @override
  void didRemove(Route route, Route previousRoute) {
    routeStack.removeLast();
  }

  @override
  void didReplace({Route newRoute, Route oldRoute}) {
    routeStack.removeLast();
    routeStack.add(newRoute);
  }
}
```

Comment: if it's `MaterialApp`, can just setup with `MaterialApp(navigatorObservers:[MyNavigatorObserver()], ...others...)`

Comment: Your code example is broken. didRemove could be a route at any position in the list, andyou need to find it first.

Answer (score 5):

Hack is here ! Add following line to your code temporarily / remove once debug is done

```
Navigator.of(context).popUntil((route) { print(route.settings.name); return false; });
```

Comment: This actually pops every single route on the stack (I stepped through the code to see what it does). Returning `false` just means "yes, pop the top route, don't stop yet". So you'll pop all the routes, and print their names, but you'll end up with an empty route stack, which will affect navigation from that point on.

Comment: As wrote above you need to comment / remove this code once you done with dubug, its just quick hack @LukeHutchison

Answer (score 3):

If you're willing to use a library, try Fluro. On the router object, it provides printTree() method to print the navigation tree.