# Is it possible to check our previous navigate pages on Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

How to check previous navigate pages?

**Example: HomeScreen > ProductListScreen >ViewCart > Payment** (Now I am in the Payment Page)

like this: `print(priousPages);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show Flutter Navigation stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54095297/show-flutter-navigation-stack)

Answer (score 4):

Pass previous page widget as parameter to the Payment widget constructor.

```
// In page you want to navigate to Payment widget.
Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
  builder: (context) => Payment(priousPages: this.runtimeType);
));
```

Or, you can use `NavigatorObserver` to receive events of navigator, and you can record changes of route in observer.

```dart
class _NavigatorHistory extends NavigatorObserver {
  @override
  void didPush(Route<dynamic> route, Route<dynamic> previousRoute) {
    print("${route.settings.name} pushed");
  }

  @override
  void didPop(Route<dynamic> route, Route<dynamic> previousRoute) {
    print("${route.settings.name} popped");
  }

  @override
  void didReplace({Route<dynamic> newRoute, Route<dynamic> oldRoute}) {
    print("${oldRoute.settings.name} is replaced by ${newRoute.settings.name}");
  }

  @override
  void didRemove(Route<dynamic> route, Route<dynamic> previousRoute) {
    print("${route.settings.name} removed");
  }
}
```

You can use `route.settings.name` to identify the route. So when you create route, you should give a route name.

```
MaterialPageRoute(
  builder: (context) => YourWidget(),
  settings: RouteSettings(name: "/payment")
)
```

Lastly, don't forget to register this observer to App.

```dart
MaterialApp(
  navigatorObservers:[ _NavigatorHistory()],
  title: "App title",
  theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
  ),
  home: homePage,
)
```

Comment: Is it possible check all previous pages without passing argument?

Comment: Yes. I give another solution in the answer. Try `NavigatorObserver` instead. @BloodLoss