# Android 13 flutter app issue in - when coming back from any screen from app it closes app even if i have not used Get.off / Navigator.pushReplacement

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation, android-13

Specific Android 13 flutter app issue

- when coming back from any screen from app it closes app even if i have not used Get.off / Navigator.pushReplacement

i have multiple screens routing from home
flow is like - home -> screen 1 -> screen 2,

now if i try to get back from screen 2 -> screen 1 by normal get.back() or Navigator.pushReplacment...
it close my app, can't share code due to client privacy issue, if anyone can help

i tried using willpopScope that didn't help as well.

Comment: are you using `BottomNavigationBar class` ?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you just don't have any screens left in your stack. You can add an observer to navigator and track exactly what happens to the screens.
Try to using the code from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56052071/12086464